# NUnit debugging a single test

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit, resharper

I use NUnit plugin from ReSharper. I can't find any way of debugging a single test. The BUG button always launches all the tests, even when I launch the debug specifically from one test method.

I'm trying to reach a breakpoint with one specific test and I don't want to reach it with the other tests.

Do you know any way of doing this? Google didn't help me on this one...

Example of my test code

```
[Test]
public void IsValidDoer_DoerValid()
{
    var mockRepositoryDoer = new Mock<IDoerRepository>();
    mockRepositoryDoer.Setup(c => c.ActiveDoers).Returns(activeDoers.AsQueryable);

    var doerValidation = new DoerValidation(mockRepositoryDoer.Object);

    Assert.IsTrue(dModel.IncludedDoers.Any());
}

[Test]
public void IsValidDoer_DoerInvalidNoQuota()
{
    var mockRepositoryDoer = new Mock<IDoerRepository>();
    var activeDoers = listDoers.ToList();
    activeDoers.First().QuotaActivity.Clear();
    mockRepositoryDoer.Setup(c => c.ActiveDoers).Returns(activeDoers.AsQueryable);

    var doerValidation = new DoerValidation(mockRepositoryDoer.Object);

    Assert.IsFalse(dModel.IncludedDoers.Any());
}
```

Comment: please post your test code I need to see how the tests are structured.

Comment: I'm just calling the same method with the same entity. I test different values for the properties of the entity that is used in the method. It could probably be put in the same test too though. I edit with some code

Comment: Just installed the latest version of resharper and all the other things and this behaviour seems to have changed! You can debug only 1 test, and cover doesn't make my tests fail any more, tests that normally pass in normal mode but used to fail with cover for some very strange reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Alongside the code is a green and yellow mark just click this and click run it will run that single test. You just left click it once you will get options and depending on what you also have installed from Jetbrains you could launch code coverage from here too.

You can also choose to append it to an already existing session of other tests or create it in a session all on its own.

[image: Resharper test]

Clarification:

Someone downvoted this so I went back and took a look and tested it both for MSTEST and NUnit. it is true it is not desirable to execute the 15 tests if you only wish to debug one. The test was conducted in visual studio 2015 with Resharper 10 and visual studio 2013 with Resharper 8. If you click on the mark in the individual test file it will indeed only run the code once.

If you run multiple tests and get a test session in Resharper's runner with three tests it will, on right click, show "debug tests", however if you only select one it only runs one test and so only hitting the code only once.

Comment: Yeah but if I RUN the test, it won't stop at the breakpoint. I have to use the DEBUG option in order to debug the test.

Comment: thats correct this then behaves in the same way or has for at least every version of resharper I've every owned. That behaviour is by design.

Comment: Appending to another session does isolate the unit test, so your suggestion is definitly a possibility!

Comment: Are you worried all the other stuff is running when you run the other test in the same session I agree that it may look that way but if you notice the ticks are only by stuff that run that pass.. its not as clean as a new session but it definately doesn't run the other tests in tandem if you only click once, which version you using ?

Comment: I'm more worried about the fact that 15 tests go through the same code and that when I put my break point in my code (not in the test), the breakpoint will be reached 15 times. I only want it to be reached for my failed test. Therefore, I need to DEBUG only that one failing test. Is my explanation clearer?

Comment: Seb I have included a test project and included this in the original answer. Tested under two versions of visual studio with two versions of resharper and on different physical boxes. I do not see it hit multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

We also where having the same issue when using ReSharper 10 as the test runner. It would run all the tests, even if I configured only a single test in the session. Also it would run all tests when I used the right click on the test ball for this test.

After installing the **NUnit3 Test Adapter** under *Tools->Extensions and Updates->Online* I could debug the tests from the regular Test Explorer of Visual Studio 2015 by right clicking and selecting *Debug selected tests*. This does only run this one test :)

Comment: I very much liked the resharper test sessions window as well as the cover feature, but the hell with it, the NUnit3 Test Adapter lets me debug only 1 test at a time if I want to so that's the way I'll go. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Also had this problem. Must be a bug with Resharper? The way I debug test is to right click on the test method 'public void Test...' and click 'Debug Tests'. Thankfully that only debugs that one test, not all.

Comment: I tried the update, but it didn't worked for some reason. For me, only Ctrl-R+T worked. Really weird but at least now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. When trying to debug single test by clicking on the circle and selecting 'Debug (bug icon)' it would Debug for all unit tests.

I resolved it by upgrading Resharper. I upgraded from Resharper Ultimate 10.0.1 to 10.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click the code of the specific test. You should see "Debug Unit Test" or something like this in the context menu.

Comment: It's Debug Unit TestS that is in the context menu, so not much to achieve from there.

Comment: Yeah, it runs the debug for all the tests